# Laravel 5.8 Cashier 7 subscription: Call to a member function create() on null

Tags: laravel-5.8, laravel-cashier

I can't get a subscription to work. I always have the same error. I use Laravel 5.8 and Cashier 7. I detail my code and my problem.

**This is the error**

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function create() on null
```

**This is the POST DATA**

```
POST Data
_token  "5z6mnrUi64GcIy0EZzHVlDgw7EDBH1DqltVS0bJS"
restaurant_id   "11"
stripeToken "tok_1HjJgFDpQQHNsFmdAKgw2ST2"
stripeTokenType "card"
stripeEmail "admin@demo.com"
```

The error seems to be in the file "\ vendor \ laravel \ cashier \ src \ SubscriptionBuilder.php" on line 204 "$ subscription = $ customer-> subscriptions-> create ($ this-> buildPayload ());"

**File .env**

```
STRIPE_KEY=Here I keep my keys

STRIPE_SECRET=Here I keep my keys
```

**File config/services.php**

I use a different model called Restaurant, instead of using the default User model. I have also tried the user model by default and the problem is the same.

```
'stripe' => [
    'model' => App\Models\Restaurant::class,
    'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET')
],
```

**File App\Models\Restaurant.php**

I implement and use the Billable class.

```
    class Restaurant extends Model implements HasMedia
    {
        use Billable;
        use HasMediaTrait {
            getFirstMediaUrl as protected getFirstMediaUrlTrait;
        }

    public $table = 'restaurants';
...
```

**File Database\Migrations\add_stripe_to_restaurants_table.php**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('restaurants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('stripe_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('card_brand')->nullable();
        $table->string('card_last_four')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
    });
}
```

**File Database\Migrations\create_subscriptions_table.php**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('restaurant_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('stripe_id');
        $table->string('stripe_plan');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('ends_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**File routes\web.php**

```
Route::post('process-subscription', 'SubscriptionController@process_subscription');
```

**File resouerces\views\restaurants\edit.blade.php**

```
<form id="silverPlan" action="{{ url('process-subscription') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
        data-key="{{ config('services.stripe.key') }}"
        data-amount="990"
        data-name="{!! trans('lang.subscription') !!}"
        data-description="{!! trans('lang.silver_plan') !!}"
        data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
        data-locale="{!! auth()->user()->language !!}"
        data-currency="eur"
        data-label="eeeeeee"
        data-panel-label="aaaaaaa"
        data-email="{{auth()->check()?auth()->user()->email:null}}">
    </script>
</form>
```

**File app\controllers\SubscriptionController.php**

The "payment" method works perfectly, I can make individual payments fine. But the "process_subscription" method is where the problem is.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Stripe\Stripe;
use Stripe\Customer;
use Stripe\Charge;
use App\Models\Restaurant;

class SubscriptionController extends Controller
{
    public function payment(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));
            $customer = Customer::create(array(
                'email' => $request->stripeEmail,
                'source' => $request->stripeToken
            ));
            $charge = Charge::create(array(
                'customer' => $customer->id,
                'amount' => 1990,
                'currency' => 'eur'
            ));
        return 'Cargo exitoso!';
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function process_subscription(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));
            $user = Restaurant::find(11);
            $user->newSubscription('main', 'price_1Hj9QLDpQQHNsFmdASQGIYPB')->create($request->stripeToken);
            return 'Suscripción exitosa! Acabas de suscribirte al Plan Plata';
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the line that throws the error and your attempts to resolve it

Comment: The error is given in this line of the controller ($ user-> newSubscription ('main', 'test') -> create ($ request-> stripeToken);), just in the file (\ vendor \ laravel \ cashier \ src \ Billable.php) at line 415 ($ card = $ customer-> sources-> create (['source' => $ token]);)